# Order of execution of Code when a KeyEvent occures

Tags: java, keyevent

Im trying to develope Snake in Java and Im using KeyListeners to get KeyEvents for the buttons w, a, s and d. I created a Class that implements KeyEvent and I added an Object of that Class to the Canvas I am drawing to.

The Game is running in a while(true) loop, where inside this loop it calls an update() Methode 60 times per second, while calling a render() Methode all the time.

My question is now regarding the KeyEvent:
If I type f.x. w, does the Method in my KeyEvent Object gets executed instantly or how is the Order of Code executed regarding the while loop I am having running? 
In my while loop is no reference at the KeyEvent Object at all, still if I type a Key the Methode inside my KeyEvent Object gets called and does whatever its supposed to do.

I would except that I had to put an if Statement inside my while(true) loop, that would read if any Buttons were pressed or that the KeyListener would run on a different thread, where it would look for any input from the Keyboard in a while(true) loop.

Comment: You posted no code, so we're forced to guess. The event listeners are executed on the Swing event dispatch thread. Your while loop is probably executing, concurrently, on the main thread or on a different thread.

Comment: I am unclear on what your question is (or you seem to have answered it yourself). That is, when a key is pressed, the KeyEvent listener method is activated without the need for any polling code in your main loop.  This is how event driven GUI's such as Windows and Swing work. The same is true for mouse movement, menu selections and other user interactions. Since you already have observed this, what exactly was your question???

Comment: Just looked it up, thanks for the answer. Made it more clear to me. One more question I would have is then, cant it get into some conflicts when both threads are updating at the same time? My question was, if the KeyEvents are running on a different Thread. There wasnt anything mentioned about that on the JavaDoc.

Comment: _Just looked it up, thanks for the answer_ Great. Perhaps you would care to answer your own question and share it with the rest of us?

Comment: Abra, that was regarding the first 2 comments above me. They answered the question pretty clear.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: That Link solved the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> You posted no code, so we're forced to guess. The event listeners are executed on the Swing event dispatch thread. Your while loop is probably executing, concurrently, on the main thread or on a different thread.
>
> docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Solved the Answer.